# Object literal notation differences in JS

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Is there a difference between how JavaScript handles the following two declarations?

```
var foo = {
    foo : true,
    bar : 1
};

var foo2 = {
    "foo" : true,
    "bar" : 1
};
```

JavaScript seems to treat them the same. If they really are the same then, is there a "correct" or preferred way to declare this?

Comment: Wrong. JSON is a string. What you asking about is called "object literal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Either form is fine for "initializing" an object (aka. declaring an object literal).

Property identifiers may be either [names, numbers, or strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) but they are all interpreted as strings:

```javascript
var foo = {
  foo  : true,
  "bar": true,
  3    : true
};
```

[See the ECMA-262 5th Edition Language Specification § 11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) for more details.

Note that the *PropertyName* construct might have changed in the 5th edition (as many things did) so browsers that do not support the most recent version of JavaScript might implement a different version of ECMAScript.

Note also that [JSON defines objects as sets of string/value pairs](http://json.org/) and strings are enclosed by quotation-marks:

```javascript
var fooJSON = '{"foo":true,"bar":true,"3":true}';
```

Comment: Note that this also means .toString() is called on objects that become properties: `var foo = {}; foo[{a:1}] = 'bar'; foo[{}] // => 'bar'; foo['[object Object]'] // => 'bar'`

Answer (score 2):

Your first sample is **not** json

```
{
    foo: true,
    bar: 1
}
```

[image]

So your second code ([*jsonlint*](http://jsonlint.com/)) IS json.

```
 {
    "foo": true,
    "bar": 1
}
```

Regarding your actual question , they are both the same.

Regarding the comment :

> If they are the same, but if the first example is not json, but the
>   second is json, what is the difference?

Let's say I have this string which should(but is not) represent json string representation :

This string comes from the server :

```
" {foo: true,bar: 1}"
```

Now I want to Parse it.

Running

`JSON.parse(" {foo: true,bar: 1}")`

Will fail :

*SyntaxError: Unexpected token f*

However :

`JSON.parse("{\"foo\": true,\"bar\": 1}")`

Will do just fine

`Object {foo: true, bar: 1}`

So here is a difference (one difference example) .

Speaking of how JS see/treats both objects (`Objects` !!! , I didn't say `json` cuz the first one is not json) - they are the same.

PS , another helpful feature is that props are considered as strings even if you didnt use `"myProp"` :

example :

```
var a={myProp:1};  //notice no `"`
var b="myProp"; 
 a[b]=2; 
alert(a.myProp) //2
```

Comment: If they are the same, but if the first example is not json, but the second is json, what is the difference? Is it their typecast or how they are interpreted?